# get multiple balances with viem getBalance function

Tags: viem

I want to fetch multiple balances with viem getBalance function.

At this moment, i am doing multiple getBalance calls (one per address)

Is there a way to do it with a single call ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can fetch balances for multiple addresses in a single call by modifying your contract's getBalance function to accept an array of addresses. Then, you can loop through the array of addresses and retrieve the balance for each address.

Comment: Hello, i have no smartcontract. I want to get the balances from my typescript webapp...